# Add p value for ggplot2 with ANOVA - three or more groups data

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, anova, p-value

I am trying to add pvalue arterisk to bar plot with ANOVA-post hoc test.
Do any one know how to make it work? I tried so many way but I could not do it.

This is the one I tried.

```
# Data preparation
df <- ToothGrowth
df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)

#Stat test
stat.test <- df %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  aov(len ~ dose, ref.group = "0.5") %>% # Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop...
  tukey_hsd()
stat.test

# Bar plot with p-values
# Add 10% space on the y-axis above the box plots
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_y_position(fun = "mean_sd")
ggbarplot(
  df, x = "dose", y = "len", fill = "#FC4E07",
  add = "mean_sd", facet.by = "supp"
  ) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test,  label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.01) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))
```

Data that I tried: ToothGrowth

There is one tutorial from here but they did with t-test. But I feel if I used t-test in this case it is not so proper.

[datanovia tut ref](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-to-ggplot-facets/?unapproved=28677&moderation-hash=b500e4e6c167e88fce7847737c2ebf90#perform-all-pairwise-comparisons)

I expect the same plot with ANOVA not t.test
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: The p values in the example are adjusted to account for the multiple hypothesis testing implied in post-hoc analysis. An omnibus ANOVA would only give you a single p value (the probability that we would see these data if the groups were all drawn from the same distribution). It does not allow for comparison between individual bars. Could you perhaps explain exactly what you are expecting to see here as the output?

Comment: @AllanCameron has already provided some great information. I just wanted to point out that if you use a t-test or ANOVA for the same data you will _always_ get the exact same results. They are the _same_ test. However, the formula for the t-test only works for 2 groups. The formula for ANOVA works for any number of groups. The tests still tell you the exact same thing and provide the exact same results.